# Gettings method arguments with ASM

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm

I found some examples that show me the location of certain method calls using a `MethodAdapter`:

```
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
        if (owner.equals(targetClass)
                && name.equals(targetMethod.getName())
                && desc.equals(targetMethod.getDescriptor())) {
            callsTarget = true;
        }
  }
```

I need the arguments, e.g., if I have `object.getText("mykey")` I would like to get the text "mykey".

Is this possible ?

Comment: Seems that I have to use visitLdcInsn to gather the arguments.

Comment: That is a relatively difficult thing to do, although it for sure works in some cases. The problem is that you'll eventually have to analyze the whole program to find out where the value originally came from and how it was moved from field to field etc. But fortunately there is something to get you started. Look at chapter 8. Method Analysis in the ASM documentation. Good Luck

Comment: What do you want if you have `object.getText(foo)`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a [framework](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/overview) which you may find useful (specifically, `procyon-compilertools`).  It would enable you to do what you ask in a more object-oriented manner than ASM.  However, the project is still early in development and subject to change, so I would not recommend using it in a production project.

You could use this as a starting point:

```
public class CallInspectionSample {
    static class Target {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Target().getText("MyKey");
        }

        public String getText(final String key) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TypeReference targetType = MetadataSystem.instance().lookupType("CallInspectionSample$Target");
        final TypeDefinition resolvedType = targetType.resolve();
        final MethodDefinition mainMethod = resolvedType.getDeclaredMethods().get(1);
        final MethodDefinition getTextMethod = resolvedType.getDeclaredMethods().get(2);

        final MethodBody mainBody = mainMethod.getBody();

        final Block methodAst = new Block();
        final DecompilerContext context = new DecompilerContext();

        context.setCurrentType(resolvedType);
        context.setCurrentMethod(mainMethod);

        methodAst.getBody().addAll(AstBuilder.build(mainBody, true, context));

        AstOptimizer.optimize(context, methodAst);

        for (final Expression e : methodAst.getChildrenAndSelfRecursive(Expression.class)) {
            if (e.getCode() == AstCode.InvokeVirtual &&
                ((MethodReference) e.getOperand()).resolve() == getTextMethod) {

                // Analyze arguments here (skip first for instance methods)...
                System.out.println(e.getArguments());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(example outputs `[initobject:Target(Target::<init>), ldc:String("MyKey")]`)